# Why scaling is null?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScalingAndRotating : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    //Camera
    public Camera playerCamera;

    //Scaling
    public bool canScale = false;
    private Scaling scaling;

    //Lights
    public DimLights dimlights;
    private Coroutine lightCoroutine;

    //Colors
    private Colors colors;

    //Rotating
    public bool stopRotation = false;
    private Rotating rotating;

    private void Start()
    {
        scaling = GetComponent<Scaling>();
        scaling.Inits();

        colors = GetComponent<Colors>();
        colors.Start();

        rotating = GetComponent<Rotating>();
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Update()
    {
        if (playerCamera != null)
        {
            //Scaling
            if (canScale == true)
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G) && canScale == true)
                {
                    Scaling();
                }
            }
        }

        //Rotate
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R) && !scaling.scaleUp)
        {
            rotating.x += Time.deltaTime * rotating.rotationSpeed;
            scaling.objectToScale.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotating.x);
            rotating.keyPressed = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.R))
        {
            rotating.keyPressed = false;
        }

        if (!rotating.keyPressed && !scaling.scaleUp && rotating.rotateBack == false)
        {
            scaling.objectToScale.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerCamera.transform.forward);
        }

        if (!scaling.scaleUp && stopRotation == false)
        {
            //rotating.x += Time.deltaTime * rotating.rotationSpeed;
            //scaling.objectToScale.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotating.x);
        }
    }

    public void Scaling()
    {
        //Flip the scale direction when F key is pressed
        scaling.scaleUp = !scaling.scaleUp;

        //Stop old coroutine
        if (scaling.scaleCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(scaling.scaleCoroutine);

        if (lightCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(lightCoroutine);


        //Scale  up
        if (scaling.scaleUp)
        {
            //Start new coroutine and scale up within 5 seconds and return the coroutine reference
            rotating.rotateBack = false;
            scaling.scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(scaling.scaleOverTime(scaling.objectToScale, scaling.maxSize, scaling.duration, playerCamera));
            if (dimlights.lightsOnOff == false)
                lightCoroutine = StartCoroutine(dimlights.dimLightOverTime(1, scaling.duration));
        }

        //Scale Down
        else
        {
            //Start new coroutine and scale up within 5 seconds and return the coroutine reference
            rotating.rotateBack = true;
            scaling.scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(scaling.scaleOverTime(scaling.objectToScale, scaling.minSize, scaling.duration, playerCamera));
            if (dimlights.lightsOnOff == false)
                lightCoroutine = StartCoroutine(dimlights.dimLightOverTime(0, scaling.duration)); ;
        }
    }
}
```

Using a break point in the Start on the line :

```
colors = GetComponent<Colors>();
```

I see that scaling is not null.

But then the game is running and it's getting after some times to the line inside Scaling :

```
scaling.scaleUp = !scaling.scaleUp;
```

And here scaling is null.

I'm calling the Scaling method from this script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class NaviConversations : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ConversationTrigger conversationTrigger;
    public ScalingAndRotating scalingandrotating;

    public void NaviConversationTrigger()
    {
        // Scale up and rotate navi here
        scalingandrotating.Scaling();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (conversationTrigger.conversationEnd == true &&
            conversationTrigger.NaviConversationInProgress == true)
        {
            // Scale down and rotate navi here
            scalingandrotating.Scaling();
            conversationTrigger.conversationEnd = false;
            conversationTrigger.NaviConversationInProgress = false;
        }
    }
}
```

If scaling was not null in the start why when the script NaviConversations is calling Scaling

```
scalingandrotating.Scaling();
```

Now scaling is null ?

Comment: either scalingandrotating is null instead of scaling or NaviConverstations is calling Scaling() before salingandrotating runs Start().

Comment: `scaling = new Scaling()`? Is there a `Scaling` component in the hierarchy?

Comment: @3Dave of this is a component then using `new Scaling ()` os absolutely forbidden! If it was not a component OP would already get a compiler error for `GetComponent<Scaling>`. Also of there was no such component on that GameObject at least in the beginning OP would already get an Exception for `scaling.Init()`

Comment: Sounds like your component is destroyed somewhere? Are you sure you have the correct `RotationAndScaling` reference? Maybe there are two in your scene and you reference the wrong one? Or e.g. a prefab